# anyone use watchify on linux? shouldn't it automatically be using inotify?

Tags: browserify, inotify, fsevents, watchify

I'm on Linux trying to use `watchify` and keep getting

```
Error: Cannot find module 'fsevents' from ~/dir
```

Why is `fsevents` even being considered by my system?  Isn't it strictly a Mac tool?  How do I get node to use `inotify` as its default file monitor instead of `fsevents`?  Specifically, I want `watchify` to wrap files before and after file changes.  Why is this?

I've tried using `node-inotify`  but for some reason I'm still getting

```
npm WARN optional Skipping failed optional dependency /chokidar/fsevents:
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: fsevents@1.0.14
```

According to [this](http://wsl-forum.qztc.io/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=32), inotify should just kick in automatically since I'm on Linux.

Comment: Try webpack & `webpack-dev-server` instead?

Comment: same happens.  requires the mac 'fsevents'

Answer (score 0):

There is no inotify support on the mac (it's a Linux kernel interface), so you cannot do this.

Comment: i reworded the original post for clarity

Answer (score 0):

instead of using `watchify/browserify` bundles, consider using `webpack --watch` as a powerful alternative for modular bundling.  if you're using linux, engage `inotify` with

```
echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf && sudo sysctl -p
```

this is [straight from the webpack docs](https://webpack.github.io/docs/troubleshooting.html) under troubleshooting